# How can I fetch only the confirmed users when using devise and Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm fetching all the users by this now.
However, I want to exclude non-confirmed users.
Their `confirmed_at` attribute is nil.

How can I?

```
@search = User.search do  
    fulltext params[:search]
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end  

@users = @search.results
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add a scope to your User model:

```
scope :confirmed, where("confirmed_at IS NOT NULL")
```

Then you have just to add the scope before the search

```
@search = User.confirmed.search do  
  fulltext params[:search]
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

**EDIT:**

Indeed, after a test, the solution above don't seem to work. The scope seems to be ignored. There's another solution:

In your `User` model you probably have a method like this:

```
searchable do 
  text :lastname, :firstname
  ...
end
```

You have to add a condition to `searchable`:

```
searchable if: proc { |user| user.confirmed? } do 
  text :lastname, :firstname
  ...
end
```

**EDIT 2:**

There is another way if sometimes you want confirmed users and sometimes all users, but you need to modify you model too.

In you `User` model:

```
searchable do 
  text :lastname, :firstname
  boolean :confirmed do
    confirmed_at != nil
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in your controller

```
@search = User.search do  
  fulltext params[:search]
  with(:confirmed, true) # true if you want confirmed users, false for unconfirmed and if you want all users you don't write this line
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

I hope this help

Comment: It still fetching all the un-confirmed users:( Does index matter? I think it ignores scope if there is index already made.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it all only in controller? For some reason, this time I want to do this all in controller:)

Comment: Unfortunately you must edit your searchable method in your model. However there is an other solution if sometimes you want to have confirmed user or unconfirmed users or all users. I made a second edition

Comment: Thanks:) In my situation. second edition looks the best! However it got this error:( `Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError (No field configured for User with name 'confirmed'):
`

Comment: Did you run `rake sunspot:reindex` in order to reindex your data in sunspot?

Answer (score 3):

I use `User.where.not(confirmed_at: nil)`. You can create a scope in your model to make it easier:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  scope :confirmed, -> { where.not(confirmed_at: nil) }

end
```

and then you can use `User.confirmed`